# How to create a product in Magento with multiple sizes and prices?

Tags: magento

I have a scenario with Magento, i am trying to have a product page with multiple price and size option. Like below

```
Product : Blanket
------------------------------------
| Size     | Price    | Qty
------------------------------------
| 10x10    | $12      | 1 --Quantity editable--
------------------------------------
| 12x12    | $12      | 1 --Quantity editable--
------------------------------------
| 15x15    | $12      | 1 --Quantity editable--
------------------------------------
                              >>Add to Cart
```

in this user should be able to enter qty for each size and even add all these sizes to cart.

Is there any option to do this in Magento?

i am trying to use grouped product but is this correct to use grouped product for my requirement? Please help if there is any other methods to do this?

Thanks,
Balan

Comment: This is grouped product, not bundled.

Comment: Yes.. when i was investigating on this.. i found what you have mentioned.. also i have updated it in the question.. thanks for mentioning..

Comment: Grouped product satisfies my frontend requirement, but for backend i am supposed to create multiple instance of same product with different sizes and prices.. and add it under associated products...

is there any way to have only single product with multiple prices and sizes in backend in product edit page...? and the front end to be same as shown in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am trying to use bundled product but is this correct to use bundled
>   product for my requirement?

Why not !?

But there is a simple way: you can use product type: Grouped for BaseProduct + type: Simple for each BaseProduct's Size.  But, in this case a 'Size' will be a 'Product name' on front-end.

Comment: yes.. this matches my front end requirement.. but for backend i have 12 or more sizes for a single product and creating individual product for each size will be time consuming..
any other known ways..? or i have to write a custom module for this?